# How to Map the nested array using map function?

Tags: node.js

I/P:

```
[
    {
        "keyword": "outdoor cushion",
        "bidInfo": [
            {
                "matchType": "EXACT",
                "theme": "CONVERSION_OPPORTUNITIES",
                "rank": 1,
                "bid": 160,
                "suggestedBid": {
                    "rangeStart": 90,
                    "rangeMedian": 160,
                    "rangeEnd": 188
                }
            },
            {
                "matchType": "PHRASE",
                "theme": "CONVERSION_OPPORTUNITIES",
                "rank": 1,
                "bid": 104,
                "suggestedBid": {
                    "rangeStart": 83,
                    "rangeMedian": 104,
                    "rangeEnd": 177
                }
            },
            {
                "matchType": "BROAD",
                "theme": "CONVERSION_OPPORTUNITIES",
                "rank": 1,
                "bid": 106,
                "suggestedBid": {
                    "rangeStart": 87,
                    "rangeMedian": 106,
                    "rangeEnd": 139
                }
            }
        ],
        "translation": "アウトドアクッション",
        "userSelectedKeyword": false,
        "searchTermImpressionRank": 18,
        "searchTermImpressionShare": 0.7346906874047442,
        "recId": "e4918800-d0bf-4f20-8776-68574e4c8339"
    },
    {
        "keyword": "cushion",
        "bidInfo": [
            {
                "matchType": "EXACT",
                "theme": "CONVERSION_OPPORTUNITIES",
                "rank": 2,
                "bid": 140,
                "suggestedBid": {
                    "rangeStart": 140,
                    "rangeMedian": 140,
                    "rangeEnd": 140
                }
            },
            {
                "matchType": "BROAD",
                "theme": "CONVERSION_OPPORTUNITIES",
                "rank": 2,
                "bid": 111,
                "suggestedBid": {
                    "rangeStart": 79,
                    "rangeMedian": 111,
                    "rangeEnd": 155
                }
            },
            {
                "matchType": "PHRASE",
                "theme": "CONVERSION_OPPORTUNITIES",
                "rank": 2,
                "bid": 107,
                "suggestedBid": {
                    "rangeStart": 76,
                    "rangeMedian": 107,
                    "rangeEnd": 149
                }
            }
        ],
        "translation": "クッション",
        "userSelectedKeyword": false,
        "searchTermImpressionRank": 60,
        "searchTermImpressionShare": 0.04246088993932697,
        "recId": "50a5705a-d79a-4f74-82bd-2836096b36fd"
    }
]
```

trying:

```
const suggestionSp: { Rank: string; searchTerm: string; matchType: string; low: string; suggestedBid: string; high: string; translation: string; }[] = [];

if (suggestions.keywordTargetList.length > 0) {
    await suggestions.keywordTargetList.map((item: { rank: string; keyword: string; matchType: string; suggestedBid: any; bid: any; bidInfo: any[]; translation: any; }) => {
        suggestionSp.push({Rank: item.bidInfo.rank, searchTerm: item.keyword, matchType: item.bidInfo.matchType, low: item.bidInfo.suggestedBid.rangeStart, suggestedBid: item.bidInfo.suggestedBid.rangeMedian, high: item.bidInfo.suggestedBid.rangeEnd, translation: item.translation });
    });
}
```

Expected O/P:

```
[{
        "keyword": "outdoor cushion",
        "matchType": "EXACT",
        "rank": 1,
        "rangeStart": 92,
        "rangeMedian": 163,
        "rangeEnd": 191,
        "translation": "アウトドアクッション"
    },
    {
        "keyword": "outdoor cushion",
        "matchType": "PHRASE",
        "rank": 1,
        "rangeStart": 83,
        "rangeMedian": 103,
        "rangeEnd": 176,
        "translation": "アウトドアクッション"
    },
    {
        "matchType": "BROAD",
        "rank": 1,
        "rangeStart": 88,
        "rangeMedian": 107,
        "rangeEnd": 141,
        "translation": "アウトドアクッション"

    }
]
```

Comment: I think your type does not match input (shouldn't it be `keyword` and `bidInfo` and `translation`?). Is I/P `suggestions.keywordTargetList`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array's `reduce` method:

```
const output = input.reduce((result, current) => result.concat(
    current.bidInfo.map(bidInfo => ({
        "keyword": current.keyword,
        "matchType": bidInfo.matchType,
        "rank": bidInfo.rank,
        "rangeStart": bidInfo.suggestedBid.rangeStart,
        "rangeMedian": bidInfo.suggestedBid.rangeMedian,
        "rangeEnd": bidInfo.suggestedBid.rangeEnd,
        "translation": current.translation
        })
    )), []);
```

Used `Reduce` syntax:

```
reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => { /* … */ } , initialValue)
```